# I am able to update a ReadOnly field inside my CSOM code

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, remote-event-receiver

I have set a field as read-only using this PnP script, the field is of type "image or hyperlink":-

```
$fieldTitle = "LinkToRiskValue"
$customfield = $Context.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($fieldTitle)
$customfield.ReadOnlyField = $true;
$customfield.UpdateAndPushChanges($true);
$Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

now i thought that this will prevent updating the item inside my CSOM code, but seems i can do this operation:-

```
context.Load(context.Site);
context.ExecuteQuery();
listItem["LinkToRiskValue"] = context.Site.Url+"/Lists/RiskValue/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=RiskValueAsset&FilterValue1=" + listItem["Title"] + "&FilterType1=Lookup";
listItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

so does this mean that i can update a Read-Only field using CSOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Please add "ReadOnlyEnforced" in field schema so that it will also prevent field value updating from code:

```
# Provide credentials over here
$creds = (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com",(ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxx" -AsPlainText -Force))
 
# Provide URL of the Site over here
# If you do not wish to pass credentials hard coded then you can use: -Credentials (Get-Credential). This will prompt to enter credentials
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://Tenant.sharepoint.com -Credentials $creds
 
# Get Context
$clientContext = Get-PnPContext
 
# -List: The list object or name of the list
# -Identity: The field object or name
$targetField = Get-PnPField -List "My New List" -Identity "LinkToRiskValue"

$targetField.SchemaXml='<Field Type="URL" DisplayName="LinkToRiskValue" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" ReadOnlyEnforced="TRUE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="Hyperlink" Group="Custom Columns" ID="{97e8adeb-b26d-427d-9a76-f7029c5b363a}" SourceID="{040f9461-79c2-4cda-8afe-f8b592a0b646}" StaticName="LinkToRiskValue" Name="LinkToRiskValue" Version="6" ReadOnly="TRUE" AllowDeletion="TRUE" ColName="nvarchar4" RowOrdinal="0" ColName2="nvarchar5" RowOrdinal2="0" />'

$targetField.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)

$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

You can firstly output the field schema using Write-Host($targetField.SchemaXml), then add  ReadOnlyEnforced="TRUE" manaually and then set like the PowerShell above.

I have tested with this property, it's working to prevent field updating even using code.

Reference:

[Lock SharePoint column, make field ReadOnly or ReadOnlyEnforced](https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/lock-sharepoint-column-make-field-readonly)

Comment: it is already set a read-only on the list level, as the field is disabled inside the quick edit grid..

Comment: Check the blog https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/lock-sharepoint-column-make-field-readonly, ReadOnlyField can be updated via Code but prevent updating in UI. ReadOnlyEnforced will prevent updating completely even using code

Comment: can you mention a link which indicates this info? thanks

Comment: https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/lock-sharepoint-column-make-field-readonly

Comment: Is there any updates ? If the answer is helpful to the question, please accept as answer so that it could help others in the forum.